# How can I render search results using Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, search

I've created a form for searching data in the DB.

This is the form:

```
<form role="search" method="post" action="{{ path('search') }}">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Cerca" name ="search">
        <span>
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And of course I also have the action in the controller:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data = $request->request->get('search');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Article a WHERE a.titolo LIKE :data')
                ->setParameter('data', $data);

    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('default/search.html.twig', array('result' => $result));
}
```

In this way, I can write in the field what I want to search, and submit the form. The form is submitted, but it renders the form again without any message or results.

If I want to render the results, do I have to create a results template where I use a for loop to render all the results?

How can I render the results?

Comment: First, you request could return any result: You have to set parameter by this way: `->setParameter('data', '%'.$data.'%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already passing `$results` to the render function. So with the required code in your template it should work without much hassle:

E.g.

```
{% for result in results %}
  <div>
    // use result, e.g. {{ result.title }} or whatever your data has to offer
  </div>
{% else %}
  <em>no results found</em>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok! thank you! 
I have another question: 
If I don't want a search input field in the form, but I want to make the search with a select field that brings the datas from the db, how can I do it?

Comment: Ok, if you results page should be that much different, I'd suggest using a distinct route (controller method) to display the results. For this, just direct the form to submit to another route. Move the code to aquire the results to this new action method then.